# Plotting data with centroids only

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, spatial-join, centroids

I am fairly new to spatial analysis and I am trying to create a map of the spatial distribution of pollution in the UK using publicly available data retrieved from https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/data/pcm-data.

The files are all downloadable as .csv and provide the x and y coordinates for the centroid of each grid cell.

I tried to import them on QGIS 3.10 in the following way: `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer`... Once I select the file, QGIS automatically recognizes the centroids as my x and y coordinates. However, when I try to plot them, my pollution concentrations do not overlap with UK geographical boundaries.

My ultimate goal is to join attributes from different datasets by location so I would need help understanding how to properly import my pollution csv files so that they overlap with my other shapefiles.

Comment: Check the CRS of your data and set it accordingly in the CSV import dialog

Comment: The defra data CRS seems to be british national grid EPSG: 27700

Comment: Many thanks to both of you, babel and @ian. I tried to import the csv file by setting EPSG: 27700. However, my pollution data still does not overlay with UK boundaries when I check with OpenStreetMap. Is there something else I am missing out here?

Comment: There is a post on github that seems to describe a similar issue. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30643 you might be missing the Grid OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb file too. It can be obtained from the proj-datumgrid-europe package at https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-europe-latest.zip. Unzip the file and put the .gsb file in the 'proj' folder under your QGIS user profile folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data contains a few header lines that probably cause some problem. When importing, be sure to set the `Number of header lines to discard` to 5 (or as many lines there are before the actual data starst) and check the box near to `First record has field names`.

Check out the preview at the bottom of how your data are imported. Does it look similar? Each column should be placed in a separate cell. Be sure to set the right delimiter above in the `File Format` section, comma in this case. Also set the CRS to EPSG:27700 as proposed by @ian. Check if x and y coordiantes are set to use the correct fields and change it manually, if necessary.

When I do this, it works perfectly with a sample download of the site you mentioned.

[image]